# How to create a view in django to edit an existing model from database?

Tags: django, view, model, edit

ich have already coded a create View (with html) to create a new Model on database. But i have no idea how to edit an existing model on database.

Comment: Are you using forms? if so you can pass the instance to the form. for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406276/how-to-load-an-instance-in-django-modelforms

Comment: To update an object from your model you need an UpdateView here the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview