# Why isn't the TextField updated after I added unique=True?

Tags: python, django

I know how to solve the problem I'm facing. But the thing is I don't know why the code behaves like that.
So I need somebody to explain why this happens.

I need to edit the TextField with a user input and show the new TextField and it works as expected when both the CharField and the TextField changed but it doesn't work when only the TextField changed. By the way when only the CharField changed, the CharField is updated.

Let me share the snippets. This is not what I actually have in my codebase.

---

models.py

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    foo_message = models.TextField(max_length=200)

class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bar_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    bar_message = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

forms.py

```py
class BarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ["bar_name", "bar_message"]
```

views.py

```py
def show_bar(request, foo_name, bar_name):
    foo = Foo.objects.get(foo_name__iexact=foo_name)
    bar = foo.bar_set.get(bar_name=bar_name)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            bar.bar_name = form.cleaned_data["bar_name"]
            bar.bar_message = form.cleaned_data["bar_message"]
            bar.foo = foo
            bar.save()
            return redirect("bar-show", foo_name, bar.bar_name)
    context = {"foo": foo, "bar": bar}
    return render(request, "bar_show.html", context)

def edit_bar(request, foo_name, bar_name):
    foo = Foo.objects.get(foo_name__iexact=foo_name)
    bar = foo.bar_set.get(bar_name=bar_name)
    form = BarForm(instance=bar)
    context = {"foo": foo, "bar": bar, "form": form}
    return render(request, "bar_edit.html", context)
```

templates
bar_show.html

```html
<h1>bar_name</h1>
<p>{{ bar.bar_name }}</p>
<h1>bar_message</h1>
<p>{{ bar.bar_message}}</p>
<a href="{% url 'bar-edit' foo.foo_name bar.bar_name %}">edit</a>
```

bar_edit.html

```html
<form action="{% url 'bar-show' foo.foo_name bar.bar_name %}" method="post">
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ form.bar_name.errors }} {{ form.bar_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.bar_message.errors }} {{ form.bar_message }}</p>
    <input type="submit" value="edit">
</form>
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("/<str:foo_name>/<str:bar_name>/", views.show_bar, name="bar-show"),
    path("/<str:foo_name>/<str:bar_name>/edit/", views.edit_bar, name="bar-edit")
]
```

---

What I want it to happen and What actually happened before is:

- only bar_name edited => successfully edited
- only bar_message edited => successfully edited
- both edited => successfully edited

And this expected behavior happened before I added `unique=True` to `bar_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)`.

---

And now what happens is:

- only bar_name edited => successfully edited
- only bar_message edited => not successfully edited
- both edited => successfully edited

When you only edited `bar_message`, the edited `bar_message` is gone and the previous `bar_message` is shown in bar_show.html.

---

To solve this problem, All I have to do is add `instance=bar` to `form = BarForm(request.POST)`.

I know that thanks to https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1228/ and [How to load an instance in Django ModelForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406276/how-to-load-an-instance-in-django-modelforms).

But what I don't understand is why "only bar_message edited => not successfully edited" happens all of a sudden after I added `unique=True`.

Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: Feels like you're always creating, never editing. Where is the code that fills the `context` variable?

Comment: I added the code that fills the `context` variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update an object from edit form in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django)